# Firewalld blocking IPv6 proxy in Fedora Linux with sing-box Core

Tags: networking, proxy, fedora, ipv6, firewalld

I'm facing an issue with Firewalld in Fedora Linux, where it seems to be blocking my IPv6 proxy when using Singbox Core in tun mode. When I stop the Firewalld service, the proxy works fine.
I suspect that the issue is related to Firewalld blocking the IPv6 connection.
How can I resolve this issue with Firewalld?

singbox core log:

```
> ERROR[0004] dns: exchange failed for mtalk.google.com. IN A: dial tcp [my server ipv6]:443: operation was canceled
```

Thanks.